# matching transaction with %in% in arules package R

Tags: r, match, arules

I need to find transactions matching some rules.
The following code used to work, but now R recognise `%in%` from the base package instead from **arules**.

```
matchRules=function(rules,transactions){
  id.match=which(transactions %in% rules)
  matchedTrx=transactions[id.match]
  summary(matchedTrx)

  return(matchedTrx)
}
```

I tried `arules::%in%` but it doesn't work.

If I use:

```
id.match=which(transactions arules::%in% rules)
```

I get Error:

```
unexpected symbol in "id.match=which(transactions arules"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21340/finding-suitable-rules-for-new-data-using-arules) answer from cross validated can help you find matching rules.

Comment: So just do `library(arules)`...?

Comment: arules is already loaded

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of %in%, I hope it helps

```
library(arules)    
st <- supportingTransactions(rules, transactions)
Transaction_IDs <- as(st,"list")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
which(arules::'%in%'(transactions,rules))
```

Comment: Error in which(arules::"%in%"(transactions, rules)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0) : 'match' requires vector arguments